# Bootstrap theme in Rails 7 with Esbuild

Tags: bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7

Bootstrap template JS functions in rails 7 doesn't work properly.

I'm using [bootstrap template](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=117868) and from the template document recommend using of Gulp, instead of that Rails 7 has an option for bootstrap with ESBuild compiling so what happening with the functions from the functions.js file for example, preload function:

```
    preLoader: function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            var preloader = e.select('.preloader');
            if (e.isVariableDefined(preloader)) {
                preloader.className += ' animate__animated animate__fadeOut';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    preloader.style.display = 'none';
                }, 200);
            }
        };
    },
```

Do I need to change the js syntax to be valid for esbuild before adding into app/javascript/application.js?